# Can't access to private cocoapods repo using https

Tags: ios, cocoa

#### Error

> [!] Unable to add a source with url `https://{company_domain}/project.git` named `ios-dev-repo`.
>   You can try adding it manually in `/Users/{use}/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

#### Premise

Actually, I have the permissions to this repo and have set up the `ssh key` in the GitLab profile. Also, I can `clone` this repo manually. What's more, I can even use `git` to set up the repo.

```
source 'gitlab@git.{company_domain}/project.git'
```

But once I use `https` for the `source`,  I encounter the above error.

```
source 'https://{company_domain}/project.git'
```

#### env

- cocoapods version: 1.6.1
- VPN: Cisco Anyconnect

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I can change `git config` globally or locally to use `git` instead of `https`.

- https://gist.github.com/taoyuan/bfa3ff87e4b5611b5cbe
- https://www.jvt.me/posts/2019/03/20/git-rewrite-url-https-ssh/

**Change git config**

```
# npm using git for https
git config --global url."gitlab@{company_domain}:".insteadOf https://{company_domain}/
```

**Check it with:**

```
git config -l
```

**How to revert**

```
git config --global --unset-all url.gitlab@{company_domain}:.insteadof
```